# How to load Music fast

Tags: android, media

I made a Music App use MusicPlayer. I see some Android Music App load music data and play music in the same time. But in my app, music only play when music data load finish. How to make app that load music and play music in the same time. Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean *MediaPlayer*, not *MusicPlayer*, right?

Comment: Also, are you trying to stream music from a local file, or from a remote service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `prepareAsync` method on a [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). It starts preparing the media player in the background and calls `OnPreparedListener` when done. MediaPlayer will take care of fetching, decoding, and playing the audio.

Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(mService.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);

mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(source);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Here's a good tutorial about [Media Player basics for Android](http://sapandiwakar.in/media-player-basics-for-android/).